# Polygon Mumbai Testnet Explorer: read/write contract error

Tags: testnets, polygon

One of the ABI in my contract is shown below. I found out the input for `_suitableProductIDss (string[][])` triggered error when I was trying to write `[[SCSG1]]` into it in Mumbai Testnet Explorer, the error shows `expected array value (argument=null, value="[SCSG1]", code=INVALID_ARGUMENT, version=abi/5.7.0)`.

There is no error when I tried it in Remix. Not sure which kind of format should I input for testnet. Request for help, thank you!

```
         {
          "inputs": [
            {
              "internalType": "string[]",
              "name": "_campaignIds",
              "type": "string[]"
            },
            {
              "internalType": "string[][]",
              "name": "_suitableProductIdss",
              "type": "string[][]"
            },
            {
              "internalType": "uint256[]",
              "name": "_expirationDates",
              "type": "uint256[]"
            },
            {
              "internalType": "uint256[]",
              "name": "_minSpends",
              "type": "uint256[]"
            },
            {
              "internalType": "uint256[]",
              "name": "_values",
              "type": "uint256[]"
            },
            {
              "internalType": "string[]",
              "name": "_valueCurrencies",
              "type": "string[]"
            },
            {
              "internalType": "uint256[]",
              "name": "_amounts",
              "type": "uint256[]"
            },
            {
              "internalType": "string[]",
              "name": "_cids",
              "type": "string[]"
            }
          ],
          "name": "createVouchers",
          "outputs": [],
          "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
          "type": "function"
        }
```

Comment: use `["SCSG1"]` instead of `"[SCSG1]"`

Comment: The error is still there. It shows `expected array value (argument=null, value="SCSG1", code=INVALID_ARGUMENT, version=abi/5.7.0)`.